# integers less than 2010 that have exactly 3 factors

Tags: number-theory

I have stumbled upon this problem during a past paper sheet and was stumped at how someone might actually do this at all by hand (no calculators and time-constrained)

I am aware that these sorts of numbers have factors a specific form after messing around, which is:

n=  $1$ x $p$ x $p^2$ where $p$ denotes a prime

However, that would require me working out the number of primes whose squares are less than 2010, identifying from the 44 normal perfect square numbers ( $x^2$ < 2010);  which by hand seems to be incredibly difficult and time taking. This leads me to believe that I'm doing something completely wrong in my approach. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong/fix my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: You can take primes to the third power , that are <  2010

Comment: Concerning the title: $n=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ has exactly $3$ factors, but is not of the form $p^3$. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Are you claiming, for example, that 10 isn't a factor of $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$?

Comment: @user10354138 Ah, I see. For me "factor" is $a$ in a term $ab$, and not a divisor, sorry. I think one should say, a number $n$ with $\tau(n)=3$, i.e., with exactly $3$ **divisors**.

Comment: Hi, to clear some things up, yes 1 and n itself is counted as a factor and for the p^3 statement it has to be a p^2 because perfect squares, in general, have only odd number of factors.

Comment: $x^2<2010$ leads to $x<44$, why is it a problem to count primes below $44$ by hand?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah, yes, factor(s) here should mean the same as divisors, as in "highest common factor (hcf)" instead of gcd that you see in some textbooks.

Comment: @Sil Nope, your absolutely right. I just thought that there would be a more "straighforward" way of doing this but in hindsight, this question was quite trivial, didn't really think properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting primes less than 44 is perfectly doable by hand inside 30 seconds at most using the [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  Indeed, they are

2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43

and you can leave them as $n=p^2$ form instead of multiplying them out (although it isn't difficult).  Indeed, I remember memorising all primes less than 200 and recite all squares less than 10000 as primary school exam questions when I was at that age about 30 years ago.

Comment: Ahh wish I could memorise all that. But thank you for your advice. So my approach was right, thanks for the aid.

Comment: But why did you had to memorize them? Like was that your own will or it was requested by your teacher? And what tehnique did you use?

Comment: @Threesidedcoin Memorising the 25 primes less than 100 is a must because there won't be enough time in the common (district-wide) exam to calculate them on the spot.  The other 21 primes from 101 to 199 is useful to avoid embarrassing mistakes because they would ask for complete prime factorisation of certain integers like 561.  As for squares, it isn't necessary to go as far as 10000, but certainly (in effect) asking for square-root of squares less than 1000 is common enough questions (and of course only needed to go up to 625 to figure the others mentally using $(50\pm m)^2$).

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is absolutely fine. All the required numbers are of the form $p^2$ with $p$ being prime and we just have to search for all prime not larger than $44$, i.e. $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $11$, $13$, $17$, $19$, $23$, $29$, $31$, $37$, $41$ and $43$.

We can use the [Eratosthenes Sieve Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find all such primes. First list all numbers from $2$ to $44$. Then delete all multiples of the first number, i.e. $2$, except $2$ itself. We circle the number $2$, which is confirmed a prime. Now the smallest number left is $3$. We then delete all multiples of $3$ other than $3$ itself. Circle $3$ to indicate that it is a prime. The smallest integer left is now $5$. Do the same thing for $5$ and repeat the procedure until we pass the square root of $\sqrt{44}$. As $\sqrt{44}$ is less than $7$, the procedure for $5$ is actually the last one. Circle all the remaining integers. They are all prime.